# removing square brackets from JSON file in R

Tags: r, arrays, json, list, to-json

I am creating a JSON file in R:

```
test <- c(list(item1 = "TEXT",
               item2 = as.array(list(start = 0,
                                     end = 99))))

write_json(test, path = "test.json" , auto_unbox = TRUE , null = "null")
```

which results in :

```
{"item1":"INDIVIDUAL_AGE","item2":{"start":[0],"end":[99]}}
```

however I need the result to be:

```
{"item1":"INDIVIDUAL_AGE","item2":{"start":0,"end":99}}
```

how can I get rid of the square brackets from item2 elements?

Answer (score 0):

For `auto_unbox`, `jsonlite::toJSON` recommends `unbox`:

```
auto_unbox: automatically 'unbox' all atomic vectors of length 1. It is
          usually safer to avoid this and instead use the 'unbox'
          function to unbox individual elements. An exception is that
          objects of class 'AsIs' (i.e. wrapped in 'I()') are not
          automatically unboxed. This is a way to mark single values as
          length-1 arrays.
```

For that, we can use `rapply`:

```r
library(jsonlite)
toJSON(
  rapply(test, function(z) if (length(z) == 1L) unbox(z) else z,
         how = "replace")
)
# {"item1":"TEXT","item2":{"start":0,"end":99}}
```

(Also works inside `write_json`.)

<sub>... though it does seem odd to me that `auto_unbox=TRUE` is not working here.</sub>

Comment: is there a different was how to do this ? I only chose a snippet of the .JSON I am working on, but by using the provided solution I would have to apply this to the entire JSON.

Comment: I know of no other way. I thought `auto_unbox=TRUE` would be the canonical way, but reading the help doc suggests otherwise. Frankly I'd think this is a bug somehow, and should be raised as one. Regardless, is there a reason you cannot use `rapply` on your entire dataset?